# Is this motor humming because of a short circuit?

Tags: induction-motor

I disassembled my vintage grinder to grease the bearings, on reassembly it hums when the switch is turned on. The centrifugal switch appears to be functioning normally. The only possible aberration to my mind is the resistance value between the motor run lead and neutral, I would've expected significantly higher. Am I overlooking something or is this motor bound for the bin?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the capacitance value, if that has failed, then the motor won't have any phase angle to turn with. if you do not have a capacitance meter, there should be an AC voltage across it while the shaft is not spinning.

Comment: Does it start or just hum? How long since in last ran? How did you check the centrifugal switch? Can you measure currents in each winding and total current? Does the shaft turn freely when you turn it by hand?

Comment: Capacitor tests at 135 uF, labeled 124-149 uF. Motor doesn't run, just hums (my bad, that was unclear), it ran fine last night. Shaft spins freely. I haven't measured current although I could if it would help. In the second photo I believe that's the run wire and neutral wire which only show 1.8 ohms which is why I thought the wires might be shorted.

Comment: It is difficult to know how much the winding resistance should be. It might be possible to estimate from the motor nameplate data. If the motor windings don't look discolored, a short seems unlikely. Checking the current in the windings would tell you a lot. Also giving the shaft a "push" would tell you a lot, but is a little risky. You would need to figure out a safe way to do it and be careful.

Comment: if you have a clamp meter measure the current through the capacitor while it's humming.

Comment: All my meters are probes but the capacitor is connected with spade terminals. I've never measured current on a cap, would I just put my meter in series between either wire and cap?

Thanks for the suggestion on nameplate data, apparently this is in the ballpark for a 1/2hp 110v motor.
Thinking about soldering a switched wire between the centrifugal clutch terminals as well to rule that out, and possibly have a manual start winding then if it fixes it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. This time was a centrifugal switch issue after all. I had tested continuity with housing almost completely closed and even shimmed switch out with washers but impossible to test continuity when both shaft bearings are fully seated, and apparently pounding the housing the last little way on was causing switch to shift. It only functions if shaft is pounded off center, all the way towards switch, after seating both bearings. Good for another 40 years, fingers crossed!